# MySQL Trigger with IF statement returning #1064

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, sql-update

I am trying to create a trigger which modifies the field `api_key_modified` in the table `wp_users` if an entry in the table `wp_bp_xprofile_data` with the `field_id` `106` got modified. The entry should only be updated for the same user.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_api_key_update AFTER UPDATE ON wp_bp_xprofile_data
FOR EACH ROW
    IF new.field_id = 106 THEN
        UPDATE wp_users SET api_key_modified = 1 WHERE id = new.user_id;
    END IF;
```

And as a result I get:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds > to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

**The code does work if i delete the IF statement** - but then it will update the data for all modifications not just to the ones with `field_id` 106.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter. Otherwise the definition ends at the first `;` which would make it incomplete

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_api_key_update AFTER UPDATE ON wp_bp_xprofile_data
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.field_id = 106 THEN
        UPDATE wp_users SET api_key_modified = 1 WHERE id = new.user_id;
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Without the `if` the code works because it is a single statement with only one `;` at the end.

Comment: I tried it with delimiters i have seen from other posts, did the same as you showed me with $$ but it didn't work. But yours does, so really thank you!!